# Partitioning a table in Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, hive

I am going through an example in the O'Reilly Hadoop book about partitioning a table. Here is the code I am running.

This code creates a table, it seems to execute without errors.

```
CREATE TABLE logs (ts BIGINT, line STRING)
PARTITIONED BY (dt STRING, country STRING);
```

When I run the below command, it returns nothing, suspicious.

```
SHOW PARTITIONS logs;
```

When I run the next part of the example code, I get an Invalid path error.

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH '/user/paul/files/dt=2010-01-01/country=GB/test.out'
INTO TABLE logs
PARTITION (dt='2001-01-01', country='GB');
```

I have definitely created the file, and I can browse it through Hue at the following location.

```
/user/paul/files/dt=2010-01-01/country=GB
```

This is the specific error.

```
FAILED: SemanticException Line 1:23 Invalid path ''/user/paul/files/dt=2010-01-01/country=GB/test.out'': No files matching path file:/user/paul/files/dt=2010-01-01/country=GB/test.out
```

Am I missing something blatantly obvious here?

Answer (score 0):

It just means file not found on the local file system at '/user/paul/files/dt=2010-01-01/country=GB/test.out'.

Answer (score 0):

The file that you created '/user/paul/files/dt=2010-01-01/country=GB/test.out' is this file stored in HDFS or local file system? If it is in HDFS then you can't use local inpath
Remove local beforehand. I don't exactly remember but you may also need to alter the table beforehand: ALTER TABLE table_name ADD PARTITION (partCol = 'value1') location 'loc1';